# Placing text on UIView in custom location

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to calculate a position to place label on the screen. The goal is to place "word" label in lower right corner of the first square block

If yellowish square is defined as

```
myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 70, 70)];
[self.view addSubview:myView];
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"FFFFEC"]];
```

Using it, i'd like to place a label in it's lower right corner

```
l1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[l1 setText:@"word"];
[l1 setFrame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x + myView.frame.size.width, 
                        myView.frame.origin.y + myView.frame.size.height,
                       700, 700)];
[l1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0]];
[l1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"CCFFFEC"]];
[l1 setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
[l1 sizeToFit];
```

This is what happens:

The matter here obviously, is in a correct offset. **Knowing the font and size of text, how can one correctly calculate it?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of a UIView is mapped to the top left corner. The issue you are having is related to the way you calculate the frame for the label. You need to calculate the frame after you call sizeToFit to make sure it is placed in the right spot after it changes the labels width and height.

You need to call this after you call `[l1 sizeToFit];`

```
[l1 setFrame:CGRectMake((myView.frame.origin.x + myView.frame.size.width)-li.frame.size.width, 
                            (myView.frame.origin.y + myView.frame.size.height)-l1.frame.size.height,
                           l1.frame.size.width, l1.frame.size.height)];
```

You subtract the width of the label from the width of the superview plus its x origin, and do the same on the y axis with the height. That way the top left of the view is placed in the right place.

Comment: Oh, i just saw that you called - sizeToFit. Updating my answer now.